# issue with iterating in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i am a super beginner in python (took an introductory to python course 4 years ago!) and I am trying to append the numbers 0-3 each in a list inside a list, so:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

i have written the code below which should work but it doesn't and i can't figure out why:

```
l = 4
data = [[None]] * l
for k in range(l):
    data[k].append(k)
print(data)
```

which produces this in the shell (don't worry about the None element in there I know how to get rid of those):

```
[[None, 0, 1, 2, 3], [None, 0, 1, 2, 3], [None, 0, 1, 2, 3], [None, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

i have been working on this for over an hour but i can't figure out what is wrong and how to fix it. any halp would be highly appriciated

Comment: `[[None]] * l` creates a list with four references to the **same** inner list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` list consists of four references to the same inner list, which is initialized to `[None]`.  As you append to this inner list in your loop, all four references to it are affected.

If you create a new list for each element, you won't have this issue:

```
l = 4
data = []
for k in range(l):
    data.append([k])
print(data)
```

In the above code, the expression `[k]` creates a new list that contains only the int value `k`.

Simpler yet:

```
l = 4
data = [[k] for k in range(l)]
print(data)
```

Comment: the thing is that this is part of a bigger code where i open a csv file and append each element in a column to one of the lists in data and then plot all of them. so i need a list with four empty lists in it so i can append my data in them.

Comment: In that type of situation my approach is usually to build the list as its contents become available rather than starting with an empty list and filling it in, but if you need to create a list of empty lists, do `[[] for _ in range(n)]`.  Building a new list for each element via comprehension will give you unique lists, whereas multiplying a list of lists gives you a list with more references to the same original list(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
l = 4
data = []
for k in range(l):
    data.append([k])
print(data)
```

`None` will also stay in the list. You are not removing it. Also, it creates a reference to the same list. so, appending to it will modify all the inner lists.

Instead of appending to an inner list, you can append a list to the list with only one element in it.

---

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
print([[k] for k in range(4)])
```

Comment: Start with empty list. There is no point multiplying `[] * l` - it is unnecessary way to write `[]`

Comment: @alaniwi, thanks. I was not using an IDE. Missed that.